# What good reason to raise an army of super-clones suffering from acute dementia?

Tags: warfare, creature-design, genetic-engineering

Super-clone's specs as follows:

- grown from a sample of Captain America DNA.

However we have engineered every clones to develop acute dementia, they will simply forget everything they have done in the past 10 minutes. I'm planning to put them up on eBay and Amazon, however I don't have any marketing experience so how do I convince my customer these toys are as good as money can buy, guaranteed performance on the battlefield... bed sold separately!

Comment: Dementia isn't just related to memories. The bones and muscles are also affected. People with acute dementia are *very* frail.

Comment: On the otherhand, PTSD shouldn't be a factor!

Comment: The title doesn't match the body, and both questions seem rather broad alone, much less together.

Comment: @EveryBitHelps: I think dementia is a common term used to describe a group of symptoms associated with a specific function of the brain usually the memory. I agree with you however the development of such illness is subjective to individual.

Comment: @Brythan: my title specifically asking for army meaning the theme is about warfare, my body is great I work out very often and sometimes exchange pointer with a group of thugs after work.(see profile)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they can't remember stuff, even if they are wonderful warriors they won't remember orders or even what side they are fighting on. This will probably result in a lot of blue on blue damage for whoever uses them.

I'm not sure what advantage an engineered lack of memory will give to these soldiers, but I can see lots of disadvantages. Maybe you can sell them as test targets for advanced weapon systems. If you can kill them, the system passes. If you can't, they won't remember being attacked.

Answer (score 2):

In our universe I don't see a lot of advantage they could have. However, in the dark era of the 41th millenium why not....

They would be the perfect inquisitorial shock troops to fight daemons and creatures of chaos. Just give them something like a vox-com, saying in their ears at any time that they are the children of the God Emperor and must destroy the daemons and kill the heretics.

Good point, these guys just couldn't be corrupted by sects and cultists. Also they would almost immediately forget every encounter with daemons, and since it is needed for the Holy Inquisition that no one ever knows daemons exists, it is perfect.

Indeed, the main problem for the Inquisition to deal with daemons is "Oh well we defeated them. Now we need to purge that all 100k men strong imperial guards regiment and all its elite troops because they know the Dark Gods and their daemons exists. And then we'll need to brain-wash once more these Space Marines over there because we can't afford to purge them. Sigh.... Being an Inquisitor is such a pain, if only I had wonderfully strong soldiers that never remembers the horrors they see."

So sell your guys to the Inquisition, it will be very pleased and perhaps you will avoid an Exterminatus on your home world for using forbidden technology.

Answer (score 2):

Sell to the enemy on the black market.
Start a whisper campaign in the right circles about the super soldiers. Next start another one about you being the (?wo)man to see.
To all but a handful of your clones, install a speaker underneath the ear that repeats the order to kill everyone that isn't one of them.
Hold 5 minute demonstrations of your soldiers' capabilities.
Sell at a premium, since you're smuggling out top secret material and the military mustn't find out. Sell to as many clients as possible.
Change your name, get plastic surgery, preferably from one of your engineered clones.
Activate the embedded speaker and let your problems take care of themselves.